# Jenkins and SonarQube does not scan the whole project

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

my current problem is that I am trying to configure Jenkins with the built-in Sonar.
My structure in SVN is as following:

```
--/
  --parent
    --pom.xml ( modules are defined in this order 
      <module>../common</module>
      <module>../model</module>
      <module>../persistence</module>
      <module>../services</module>
      <module>../webservices-model</module>
      <module>../webservices</module>
      <module>../web</module>
      <module>../fidb-client</module>
      <module>../batch</module> )
  --common ( every modul has its own pom.xml as well! )
    --pom.xml
  --model
  --persistence
  --services
  --webservices-model
  --webservices
  --web
```

Now what I tried:

```
In Jenkins under source code management I specified the repository url as: `http://xyz/svn/parent/`
Local module directory: `./parent`
```

I did this for every module defined above.

Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment is checked

```
Root POM: `pom.xml`
```

Invoke top level Maven targets ( I did this for every modul as well )

```
-Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
-Dsonar.login=test
-Dsonar.password=test
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.net
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=test.lan.at
-f ../parent/pom.xml clean install
```

However, I always get the following error when trying to build at the persistence modul ( common, modul and paret are working ), in Eclipse, however, it works without problems:

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mifid2-persistence: Could not resolve dependencies for project at.sitsolutions.mifid2:mifid2-persistence:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: at.sitsolutions.mifid2:mifid2-fidb-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2: Could not find artifact at.sitsolutions.mifid2:mifid2-fidb-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Maybe, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for your help